# How do I get a word inside a file at given position?

Tags: crystal-lang

How to get a word inside a file at given position

```
def get_word(file, position)
  File.each_line(file).with_index do |line, line_number|
    if (line_number + 1) == position.line_number
      # How to get a word at position.column_number ?
    end
  end
end
```

This should work like this:

File: `message.md`

```
Dear people:

My name is [Ángeliño](#angelino).

Bye!
```

Calls: `get_word`

```
record Position, line_number : Int32, column_number : Int32

get_word("message.md", Position.new(1, 9))  # => people
get_word("message.md", Position.new(3, 20)) # => Ángeliño
get_word("message.md", Position.new(5, 3))  # => Bye!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, this will give you a hint. Please, be advised that this implementation never treats a punctuation mark as a part of a word, so the last example returns `Bye` instead of `Bye!`.

```
def get_word_of(line : String, at position : Int)
  chunks = line.split(/(\p{P}|\p{Z})/)

  edge = 0
  hashes = chunks.map do |chunk|
    next if chunk.empty?
    {chunk => (edge + 1)..(edge += chunk.size)}
  end.compact

  candidate = hashes.find { |hash| hash.first_value.covers?(position) }
                    .try &.first_key

  candidate unless (candidate =~ /\A(?:\p{P}|\p{Z})+\Z/)
end

p get_word_of("Dear people:", 9)                       # => people
p get_word_of("My name is [Ángeliño](#angelino).", 20) # => Ángeliño
p get_word_of("Bye!", 3)                               # => Bye
```

Answer (score -1):

A handy way to get the numerical position of a section of a string is to use a regex like so:

```
filename = "/path/to/file"
File.each_line(filename).each_with_index do |line, line_number|
  term = "search-term"
  column = line =~ %r{#{term}}
  p "Found #{term} at line #{line_number}, column #{column}." if column
end
```

Outputs: `"Found search-term at line 38, column 6"`

Comment: I don't know the `term` (word) to search, only its position :-p